# Linux Bash Sed one liner change config value - with space or no space

Tags: regex, bash

I need a Sed one liner to change a `key = value` pair in a config file, respecting the space or even no space between `key` and `=`

```
// config_file could look like this
key = oldValue
key=oldValue
key= oldValue
key =oldValue
keyABC = doNotMatchThis
```

What I got so far is this

```
sed -i '/key/s/= .*/= newValue/' config_file
```

The result will be

```
key = newValue
key=oldValue
key= newValue
key =oldValue
keyABC = newValue
```

`keyABC` changed also (very bad!). How can I achieve this?

What I want is

```
key = newValue
key=newValue
key= newValue
key =newValue
keyABC = doNotMatchThis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -i '/^key *=/s/=.*/= newValue/' config_file
```

The line qualitifier pattern is `^key *=`:

- `^` - start of string
- `key` - a `key` string
- `*=`  - 0 or more spaces and then `=`.

The substitution command is `s/=.*/= newValue/`: it finds `=` and any 0+ chars after, and replaces with `= newValue`.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/WWiIBb).

```
s="key = oldValue
key=oldValue
key= oldValue
key =oldValue
keyABC = doNotMatchThis"

sed '/^key *=/s/=.*/= newValue/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
key = newValue
key= newValue
key= newValue
key = newValue
keyABC = doNotMatchThis
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed.

```
sed -i -r 's/^(key *= *).*/\1newValue/' file
```

Output:

```
key = newValue
key=newValue
key= newValue
key =newValue
keyABC = doNotMatchThis
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's/\(key[[:space:]]\{0,1\}=[[:space:]]\{0,1\}\).*/\1 newValue/g' file
```

In case you want to match both tabs and spaces, use this instead:

```
sed -i 's/\(key[[:blank:]]\{0,1\}=[[:blank:]]\{0,1\}\).*/\1 newValue/g' file
```

Also to limit the number of occurences of those spaces, change limits in `\{0,1\}` and in case you accept any number of spaces,

```
sed -i 's/\(key[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*\).*/\1 newValue/g' file
```

Also, the same can be done with a little more simplicity with `awk`(well I think so):

```
newVal="your_new_value"
awk -F= -v newVal="$newVal" '/ *key *=/{$2="="newVal}{print}' file
```

To retain changes in file:

```
newVal="your_new_value"
gawk -i -F= -v newVal="$newVal" '/ *key *=/{$2="="newVal}{print}' file
```

Comment: @kmgt, does it show some error? or wrong results? On my machine it works correctly

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting. It shows me the result directly in terminal and the result is right. But when I open the file nothing changed in there. Still `oldValue`s.

Comment: @kmgt, apologies, i didn't write the `-i` flag.

Comment: Alright, now it's working. Thank's for your update. The second command with tabs does not match.

Comment: @kmgt, again, it works on my machine, most probably some compatibility issues. But in case [:blank:] doesn't work, you can  give a try to `sed -i 's/\(key[\t[:space:]]*=[\t[:space:]]*\).*/\1 newValue/g' file`